# Why did my flag get revised?

Tags: support, questions, flagging, disputed-flags

My flag got revised; not declined just revised meaning I got 11 flags instead of 10 today.
It was on [this question](https://superuser.com/q/292833/1678725) for it being about software recommendations; I reflagged it.

Comment: It seems that it may have just aged away because no one else voted to close.

Comment: @Mokubai I didn't vote close I flagged it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the comments:

> @Mokubai said: It seems that it may have just aged away because no one else voted to close

You replied:

> > I didn't vote close I flagged it.

Right - That's the point.  If you flag a question as being about a software recommendation, then it goes into the "Close votes" review queue (which you'll get access to at 3,000 rep).  From there:

- If within a certain period of time (4 or 10 days, depending on the activity level on the question, I believe), it gets a close-vote from another user (even a single vote), then your flag will get marked "Helpful".  The question may not receive enough votes to be closed, but as long as there's a single close-vote, you get the "Helpful" credit.
- If the question ages out of the close-votes queue without getting a close-vote, which [this one apparently did](https://superuser.com/posts/292833/timeline) then your flag just disappears with it.  You don't get dinged with a "declined" flag, but it won't count as "Helpful" either.

Comment: @TheRandomGuyNamedJoe12 If you follow the link I posted in the answer to that question's history page, you'll see the "Close Votes - Invalidated".  If it had received a close-vote during that period, you would see your flag marked as "Helpful".  Since you say it isn't marked as "Helpful" and no longer, I assume, "Pending", then there were no close-votes during the period of time the question was in the Review queue.

Comment: @TheRandomGuyNamedJoe12 Also, If you go to your profile and click where it says "1 Helpful Flag", you should be able to see the number of your flags that have aged away.